# Implementing Linear Diagonal Movement Relative to Camera Rotation

Tags: c++, game-physics

So far I've implemented horizontal (X-axis) and vertical (Z-axis) linear movement for the player in a 3D game. Using the code shown below, the player is able to move relative to the camera's Y-axis rotation.

`rotationOffset` represents the direction:

- 0.f = Forward
- 90.f = Right
- 180.f = Backwards
- -90.f = Left

```
velocity.x = glm::sin(cameraYRotation + rotationOffset) * speed;
velocity.z = glm::cos(cameraYRotation + rotationOffset) * speed;
```

I use key press & release events to set the velocity using the code above.

However, I'm not sure how I can implement diagonal movement, such as when the player is moving Forward + Right.

If the player is initially moving Forward, but then starts moving to the right as well to move diagonally, how would can I apply that change to the velocity?

Should I create more variables to keep track of the keys being pressed?

Furthermore, how do I deal with key releases (e.g. Player initially moves diagonally Forward + Right, but then releases the Right key, thus only moves Forward)?

Comment: Don't 45 and -45 work? Like **RIGHTDIAGONAL = 45.f** and **LEFTDIAGONAL = -45.f**. Check the input in every frame and update the angle and velocity accordingly. How about that?

Comment: So then I should keep track of the player's movement /or the keys being pressed? Because I'm not tracking any of those, if I were to press the `Forward` and `Right` key together, it would send two inputs: Foward and Right (in an arbitrary order).

Comment: I don't exactly know how you designed the code. But, if the direction of the player can change during gameplay based on inputs, checking inputs and updating those variables in every frame seems like the only option.

Comment: If *FORWARD* and *RIGHT* are pressed in a single frame, then move diagonally and so on...